# Creating Google In-App Products using Google APIs

Tags: android, node.js, google-api

My request is

```
`{
  "packageName": "com.test.package",
  "sku": "title",
  "status": "inactive",
  "subscriptionPeriod": "P1M",
  "purchaseType": "subscription",
  "listings": {
    "en-US": {
      "title": "title",
      "description": "title"
    }
  },
  "defaultLanguage": "en-US",
  "defaultPrice": {
    "priceMicros": "100000000",
    "currency": "SGD"
  }
 }`
```

to the post call for inserting a product (reference : [[https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/inappproducts]](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/insert)).
Getting error response for this request

```
`{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "androidpublisher",
        "reason": "inAppProductRegionsMissingPricing",
        "message": "Must provide a price for each region the app has been published in."
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Must provide a price for each region the app has been published in."
  }
}`
```

Can anyone explain this error, because i have set a default price ?
And also how do i get all the countries list and its currencies in which the app is published in from google play console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to PRICING & DISTRIBUTION Page of your app in https://play.google.com/apps/publish/

In Countries find out how many region you have selected for this app.

while inserting the in app product you have provide price for all region you have selected.

so suppose if you have selected Pakistan as region

- PK (2 letter ISO country code as key for each price for each region within price array)

then you request should be

`{
    "packageName": "com.test.package",
    "sku": "title",
    "status": "inactive",
    "subscriptionPeriod": "P1M",
    "purchaseType": "subscription",
    "listings": {
        "en-US": {
            "title": "title",
            "description": "title"
        }
    },
    "defaultLanguage": "en-US",
    "defaultPrice": {
        "priceMicros": "100000000",
        "currency": "SGD"
    },
    "prices": {
        "PK": {
            "priceMicros": "100000000",
            "currency": "SGD"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there anyway around to get all the countries that the app is published in, through google API? Because there are several countries tick marked.

Comment: i don't think so, i haven't found any way.

As you can access the google play so you have to construct static list of all the countries you have checked and make array of their ISO code and loop around it and assign price..

Comment: Okay, thanks for all your efforts! Anyway, google should have provision on that too, i wish.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to do this, imagine you having to send all that to about 150 countries. You can just parse the `['autoConvertMissingPrices' => true]` when inserting or updating a product so Google does the conversion.

In my case here is what I do. `{ 'autoConvertMissingPrices' => true }`

```php
$purchase = $service->inappproducts->update(
  'app.package.name',
  'product_sku',
  $product,
  ['autoConvertMissingPrices' => true]
);
```